# images[Position].setImageResource(..) not by clicking, but by position where i want

Tags: android, drawable, android-imageview

i'm designing a 8*8 board for reversi game. For initializing board i've used ImageAdapter.

I need to change image resources in 2 different cases.

First: -that is usual- when i click on an image. That's OK.

Second: when clicked on a position, i have to change some other images on the board too. But i don't know HOW????

In other words, how can i write:

`images[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.image);`

instead of: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);`

which position is an integer that shows the position where i want to change it's image. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing this in `getView` in your adapter:

```
if(position == 0) imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
else if(position == 1) imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
// etc etc.. you can set different images for different positions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
images[position]=R.drawable.image;//replace image in list with new image
          gridView.invalidateViews();//

  imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//imageAdapter is object of adapter
```

Comment: Hi mukesh. Can i chat with you please? i want to show you some of my codes. I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP!

Comment: thank you, mukesh. but here only 585 characters is allowed. How do i send you? (your email? or is there other ways?)

Comment: i wanna cry!! i look everywhere in your profile, there were no email address. When i go to my own profile i see my email. but in yours, either is not shown, or you have not saved any email..!

Comment: it took a long time creating a word document, explaining code. sorry, but now is sent. you can check your email.